# BO Universe DB migration

Tags: business-objects

I have a situation in migration of oracle DB to sybase DB. what is the best way to migrate universe.

few approaches that came into my mind..

1. create a new connection with sybase DB
2. create a new connection with table refresh.

Any other suggestions... or which one will be the best in the above two...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: modifying the connection does not work ? BO is on top of the DB, should not be effected by the vendor as long it's supported.

Answer (score 0):

Approaches :

- Create all you need for the connection (OBDC)
- Migrate your table (one for one)
- Change the universe connection

Maybe you could improve some issue if you have function in your universe not supported in sybase (sometime there is some difference in the SQL language between two different vendor).